# Issue with building Go 1.6

Tags: go, build

I am trying to build and install go 1.6 in linux.(amd64).

I have already installed go 1.42.

I keep getting the error : Import cycle not allowed while building dist.

I have go symlinked to /usr/bin from /usr/lib/golang/bin/go. 
I have set GOROOT_BOOTSTRAP=/usr

```
GOARCH="amd64" 
GOBIN=""
GOCHAR="6"
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/usr/share/gocode"
GORACE=""
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/bin/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
GOROOT="/usr/bin"
CC="gcc"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
```

Any Idea what is going wrong here ?

Comment: if you are looking for a quick installation, use homebrew: `brew install go`.

Comment: I like to install from the binary tarball by using make.bash --clean-all. I want to know the source of the "import cycle" here.

Comment: `/usr/bin` is definitely not a good value for GOROOT, and I doubt `/usr` is the correct value for GOROOT_BOOTSTRAP. GOROOT should be the root directory of the tarball you unpacked (even better is put in in `/usr/local/go` and don't set GOROOT), and GOROOT_BOOTSTRAP should be the GOROOT for the existing go1.4 installation. It has nothing to do with where you may have symlinked the `go ` executable (but you should probably add the bin dir to your path, rather than relying on the symlink)

Comment: Thanks JimB your suggestion worked! I finally understand the meaning & purpose of GOROOT & GOROOT_BOOTSTRAP.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks JimB!

The problem was due to the incorrect value for GOROOT_BOOTSTRAP. It should be set to the existing go 1.4 installation directory holding all the go code & libraries and not just the "go" executable.